DBA_SEGMENTS don't show my new partition table information on oracle 19c
We have a new partition table. I wanted to get the, each sub partition size in GB.
But, couldn't find these anything related to partition table in dba_segments.
SELECT owner, segment_name, segment_type, partition_name,bytes/1024/1024/1024 "GB", tablespace_name
FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION',
'INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'INDEX SUBPARTITION')
AND SEGMENT_NAME LIKE 'TABLENAME'
ORDER BY bytes DESC;

Tried with above query, but I don't see any of the records with my table name.
Please help, in locating my new partition table related size information for each sub partition.

Does the table have data?  Did you use deferred segment creation when creating the object?

Hi Justin
Yes, this table have date. It was created from existing table and I can see data across several partitions

I would assume a typo for the segment name

:) it is the correct name, I used.

I don't think so, because a table and an index and index and table partitions cannot have all the same name.

Starting with 11.2, Oracle has a parameter called deferred_segment_creation which defaults to TRUE. When creating a new table or partitions, it creates the logical objects but does not yet allocate space in the tablespace, meaning there is no physical segment. dba_segments displays physical segments only. You can still see your logical objects in dba_objects, dba_indexes, dba_tables, dba_tab_partitions, etc..  where a column named SEGMENT_CREATED will say 'NO', telling you that it hasn't created a physical segment yet for the object.
As soon as you insert a single row, it now must create a physical segment and allocate space in the tablespace. This is when rows will show up in dba_segments.
So, to see your table, start with the logical object views and outer join back on dba_segments to get size, interpreting a lack of any such row to mean no segment and therefore size 0 bytes. You will also need to modify your query to show the indexes separately, as that requires mapping your table name to the index names before you can find them in dba_segments:
SELECT sp.table_name,sp.partition_name,sp.subpartition_name,s.segment_type,NVL(s.bytes,0) bytes
  FROM dba_tab_subpartitions sp,
       dba_segments s
 WHERE sp.table_name = 'MYTABLENAME'
   AND sp.table_owner = s.owner(+)
   AND sp.table_name = s.segment_name(+)
   AND sp.subpartition_name = s.partition_name(+)
 UNION ALL
SELECT i.index_name,sp.partition_name,sp.subpartition_name,s.segment_type,NVL(s.bytes,0) bytes
  FROM dba_indexes i,
       dba_ind_subpartitions sp,
       dba_segments s
 WHERE i.table_name = 'MYTABLENAME'
   AND i.owner = sp.index_owner(+)
   AND i.index_name = sp.index_name(+)
   AND sp.index_owner = s.owner(+)
   AND sp.index_name = s.segment_name(+)
   AND sp.subpartition_name = s.partition_name(+) 


Hi @Paul
The parameter "deferred_segment_creation" is set to FALSE.
The column "segment_created" in the "dba_tab_partitions" view shows "YES".
Additionally, this partitioned table was created using data from another table, which contains a large volume of data spread across several partitions.

@vigneshwarreddy, Please show the actual create table statement used, and the exact query (without changing the table name to 'TABLENAME'). It's probably a simple query mistake but we can't be of help if we don't see the real values used.
